# Displaying JSON data received through API call and axios into a Bootstrap-Vue Table

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am trying to display data I have received through an API call using Axios into a tidy Bootstrap-Vue table.

Using Axios, the title for each clinical tab index is updated. Currently, I am displaying the clinical tab title for each index using a v-for loop, and thus am displaying the data for each tab in on single row. I would like to split each tab into its own table, but am not sure on how to approach this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
data: () => ({
            // reactive data property of the component.
            //test: 'delete later',
            loading: true,
            clinicaltabs: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    title: "Observations Go Here",
                    htmlcontent: "Observations (Tab 1)"
                },
                {
                    id: 2, 
                    title: "Medications Go Here",
                    htmlcontent: "Medications (Tab 2)"
                },
                {
                    id: 3,
                    title: "ADLs Go Here",
                    htmlcontent: "ADLs (Tab 3)"
                }

            ]

        }),
```